# How can I permanently add a new path to the 'PATH' environment variable of the current user on Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, wmic

I'm working on Windows 7.  How can I permanently add a new path to the 'PATH' environment variable of the current user?

I tried to do so with wmic:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "name='Path' and username='<%USERNAME%>'" set VariableValue="%Path%;%NEW_FOLDER_PATH%"
```

The result was:

```
No Instance(s) Available
```

And nothing was affected.  However if I try with the following with Administrative privilege:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "name='Path' and username='<system>'" set VariableValue="%Path%;%NEW_FOLDER_PATH%"
```

It could always succeed.

The NEW_FOLDER_PATH doesn't contain any blank spaces.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically or any way possible?

Comment: @Mario: Any possible way is acceptable.  I'm trying it in a Windows Batch file so this is my most desired way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around a bit, and it seems like it expects a domain/computer name together with the user name rather than brackets.

Try running this:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "name='Path'"
```

This will return all results, essentially one per user. You'll notice that users use the full name, like `Mario-PC\Mario` rather than `Mario` or (what you've tried) `<Mario>`.

To fix your command line, you'll want to look for the name like that (note the escaped backslash!):

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "name='Path' and username='%USERDOMAIN%\\%USERNAME%'"
```

Comment: Great!  That works!  Yeah.. I should have thought of that earlier...